# Multi site clarification

Tags: installation, admin, multisite

I've done some reading about multisite over at WordPress.org and looking to see if I'm understanding correctly.

My current blog domain is somewhat locale restricted by name. However, much of my content is not. So, within the next 2 - 3 months I plan to use another domain that I own as a "master" domain and have my current site within that.

The way that my current blog is structured on the host is like this:

- WordPress URL: h..p://www.mysite.com/wordpress
- Site address URL: h..p://www.mysite.com
- Directory structure on the host: /home/myusername/mysite.com/wordpress

According to the WordPress.org site: "This means each additional site in your network will be created as a new virtual subdomain or subdirectory." So, what changes (if any) will I need to make to my current site in order for it to be a subdomain of the new site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you need to do

Create a NEW multi site blog on the new "master" domain with WP 3.0

Create a new empty blog the the url h..p://www.mysite.com/oldblogname

Export you old site and input inport into the new blog

You need to check that all the images get copied to the new site OK otherwise keep the old blog in place to serve the images

And you will have I nice new blog

To keep it tidy you should put a 304 redirect from the old URL to the new URL

Something like this should (not tested) into a .htacces file in the old blog folder

```
RewriteEngine on
#
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.websiteA.com/oldblogname/ $1 [R=301,L]
```